# Django: get_fieldsets Unknown fields

Tags: python, django, forms, field, formset

I'm facing a little situation here. I have a model named Product that contains basic information about the product, and a model named SpecificProductInfo that contains a pk pointing towards a Product, a pk pointing towards a Language (another model) and other information in the given language

Not only it's not possible to create a SpecificProductInfo by yourself, but whenever you create a Product (in the admin), the SpecificProductInfo fields should appear too (you can't create a product if you don't give its name in every language used by your website for example). For this, I wanted to use the 'get_fieldsets' function. But Im meeting this error:

'Unknown field(s) (name-Chinese, name-English) specified for Product. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ProductAdmin'

The weirdest thing is that it happens one every two times. When I load the admin page, I don't have any mistakes. Then the mistake appears when I click on save. But if I change a meaningless thing in my code (for example I add a space and then I remove it and save the code) and reload the page, it works. But then the next time it won't! I just don't get it!
Here is my code! Thank you for helping me figure it out!

```
language_fields = collections.OrderedDict()
settings = SiteSettings.objects.get(pk=1)

class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        fields = ('picture', 'phone', 'email', 'website', 'notes',)
        model=Product

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for lang in sitesettings.active_languages.all():
            name_title = 'name-{0}'.format(lang.code)
            name_label = 'Name ({0})'.format(lang.name)

            language_fields[lang.id] = (name_title, )
            self.fields[name_title] = forms.CharField(label=name_label,max_length=255)


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form=ProductAdminForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        language_index = 1
        for lang in language_fields.values():
            fieldsets[0][1]['fields'].insert(language_index, lang[0])
            language_index = language_index + 1

        return fieldsets

admin.site.register (Product, ProductAdmin)
```

PS: Im working on Django 1.6.0 and Python 3.2.5
PPS: I didnt specify the includes
PPPS: Settings is a model where one of the fields is the active languages (M2M Language).

Thank you very much for your help!
Have a great day